# Constructive Comments Deleted?

Tags: discussion, comments, answers

[Must write alert before event is fired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23066886/must-write-alert-before-event-is-fired#23066940) <-- this question here had comments explaining why the answer was wrong, but suddenly they were all deleted. They were not rude, offensive or even off topic, they explained why the answer was wrong and how to fix it.

No big deal or anything, I'm just a bit confused.

Comment: Did they become obsolete once the answer was edited?

Comment: Not so much -- the answer was more or less still wrong and had the same explanation of jQuery's `on` method

Comment: They were flagged as being obsolete after the answer was edited and were then removed by a moderator.

Comment: @BradLarson I'm afraid they weren't obsolete. The answerer is still wrong about the `click` vs. `on` =/ (not to mention that the event handler wasn't the issue)

Comment: Probably your best bet is to add an answer that addresses the issue(s) raised by the comments, and explains why this answer is correct.

Comment: @KateGregory thanks, but the question itself is rather poor quality, so this was more of a curiosity meta than an actual problem lol. I'm just going to let it be, trust the mods, and close vote.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That's my fault, mostly. A group of comments were flagged, starting with:

> This is false, actually.

which is not terribly useful. Another comment told the author of the answer to read the documentation and come back with any follow-up questions.

There were a total of five comments on that post flagged for a variety of reasons, and in my haste to clean up, I deleted all of them. After reading through them again, more carefully, I think two of them were actually useful. One of them was already reposted, and I undeleted the other. Sorry about the mix-up.

Comment: No worries Bill, I'm not in the slightest upset. I'm just a curious guy is all! :D